# 'for statement' without a colon

Tags: python, syntax

```
test_keys = ["Rash", "Kil", "Varsha"]
test_values = [1, 4, 5]
  
# using dictionary comprehension
# to convert lists to dictionary
res = {test_keys[i]: test_values[i] for i in range(len(test_keys))}
  
# Printing resultant dictionary 
print ("Resultant dictionary is : " +  str(res))
```

above, there should be an ending colon " **:** " after 'for statement' like for i in range(3) :

but this line didn't put " : " at the end of range()
`res = {test_keys[i]: test_values[i] for i in range(len(test_keys))}`
This is totally out of syntax i knew,
how this is possible?
perhaps is it syntax for dictionary only?

Comment: The colon `:` means that the following block of code refers to the line that contains that colon. However, in comprehensions, you don't need the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with sets, dictionaries, lists and generators and is called set, dictionary and list comprehension respectively or generator expression:

```
set_comprehension = {i for i in range(10)}
dict_comprehension = {i:i for i in range(10)}
list_comprehension = [i for i in range(10)]
generator_expression = (i for i in range(10))

print(set_comprehension)
print(dict_comprehension)
print(list_comprehension)
print(generator_expression)
```

Output:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fe9e8999dd0>
```

Comment: You can also read the full spec in the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).

Comment: For generators, it's called *generator expression*, not *generator comprehension*.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is called "dictionary comprehension" and it's an alternative syntax for creating an iterable.

It comes in useful quite often.

Similar to list comprehension:

```
newlist = [expression for item in iterable if condition]
```

Comment: no it isn't, it's dictionary comprehension if it's in a dictionary

Comment: Spot on @Nin17. I'd gotten into a bad habit of using the same term for both. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In python, the `:` is used to indicate that this line we enter a new bloc of code (deeper level of indentation starting next line). 
Ex:

```
if condition:
    pass #Deeper indentation
for i in range(10):
    pass #Deeper indentation
while True:
    pass #Deeper indentation
#And many others
```

In list comprehension everything is on the same line so the `:` is not required and will cause issue since the next line don't have deeper indentation.